# Execute layers in tensorflow multiple times

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm wanting to get a project migrated over to Tensorflow 2. The project in question is [NeuroSAT](https://github.com/dselsam/neurosat).

It seems like I can create the MLPs with tf.keras.layers.Dense and LSTMs with tf.keras.layers.LSTM. There's some tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul calls that I think can be handled with tf.keras.layers.Dot.

Where I'm really getting lost is that this project utilizes some number of message passing rounds followed by running the output of the final round of voting through a voting MLP layer. In the original project, the author uses Tensorflow while loops, calling the MLP/LSTM/matmul each time. Is that how it has to be done in Tensorflow 2 or is there some way to tell it to execute the first N number of layers X times and then the remaining layer(s) once? Maybe I have to add these message passing layers multiple (N) times to my model?

I've been looking at Tensorflow docs on writing a training loop from scratch as well as subclassing tf.keras.Model and overriding train_step, but the examples I see don't really seem to be doing what I'm trying to do, so I feel like I've been going down the wrong path.